# Including Typescript files from an unknown location

Tags: typescript

I have some fairly simple Typescript files that reference type definitions. Using  works in individual cases. However the ts files can occur in various locations, so we don't know the path of the included files relative to the ts file. Is there a way to specify where the file is located at compilation time, rather than when the source is written? In C++ we would use a -I compiler option.

We can't rely on a specific IDE for this. It has to be within TSC or some similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such option and I don't see a way how to work it around.

**Spec:**

> A comment of the form ///  adds a dependency on
>   the source file specified in the path argument. The path is resolved
>   relative to the directory of the containing source file.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1111-source-files-dependencies

**Source code:**

```
export function resolveTripleslashReference(moduleName: string, containingFile: string): string {
    const basePath = getDirectoryPath(containingFile);
    const referencedFileName = isRootedDiskPath(moduleName) ? moduleName : combinePaths(basePath, moduleName);
    return normalizePath(referencedFileName);
}
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/program.ts#L33